# How can I send only notification requests in docker

Tags: python, django, ajax, docker

I am developing a website where there is a buyer and seller. They can chat each other. I know there is a library in django thats called Django channels. But I dont want to use it. I builded such a thing on my own. Every thing works fine. But when i try to integrate a notification system the server loads a lot. Everything seems. But I got a plan to solve this issue. But I dont know it will work. Thats why I am posting a qustion about the idea.

For Notification system I requested GET method in every pages. So Is it possible to send only the notification reuqests to docker so that I could reduce the load. Or can someone give me an idea to solve this Issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. "_server loads a lot_" what do you mean by that? Do you mean the server loads all of the notifications? You'll need to write some logic to handle that, something like show the last N notifications and add pagination.

Comment: I mean i am sending continuous request in all of the pages so that receivers doesnt have to load or refresh the website to get notification. are you clear @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Please add the clarification properly to your question. It seems you want to say that you make AJAX requests from the client, very frequently at that, which is the problem. "_I builded such a thing on my own_" also doesn't explain that. Instead of "_server loads a lot_" you likely want to say "there are too many requests". Rather than looking into Docker I would suggest you to use Websockets (which would lead you to Django channels in case of Django) as your use case fits well for that.

Comment: But I dont want to use django channels or web sockets. Can I send ajax requests to docker only ?? @AbdulAzizBarkat